# use variable in pdo array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

simple question, I think.

I have the following pdo statements:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT person,job FROM orgstructure where department=:dept order by id asc"); 
$sth->bindParam(':dept', $departmentname, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$sth->execute(); 
$dataArray = $sth->fetchAll();
echo $dataArray[0]['person'];
echo $dataArray[1]['job'];
```

the two echos are to test, which work 100%.

Later on in my form, I have a `for loop` in whcih I provide select box options, based on the outputs of the pdo, as below:

```
<table>
<?
    for ( $i = 1; $i <=50; $i++ ) { 

        ?>      
            <tr>
                <td> Job <? echo  $i; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <SELECT NAME=job<? echo $i; ?> id=job<? echo $i; ?> style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red"> 
                    <? echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[$i]['job']."</option>"; ?>
                    <option>
                    <?=$optionjobs?> 
                    </option>
                    </SELECT>
                </td>
                <td> Person </td>
                <td>
                <? echo $i."person: ".$dataArray[$i]['person']."job: ".$dataArray[$i]['job']; ?>

                    <SELECT NAME=person<? echo $i; ?> id=person<? echo $i; ?> style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red">
                    <? echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[$i]['person']."</option>"; ?>               
                    <option>
                    <?=$optionpersons?> 
                    </option>
                    </SELECT>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

This however does not work. the select statement is correct and works if I replast the $dataarray with text.

I am assuming the issue is with the $i counter being used inside the $dataArray? any suggestions?

Thanks as always,

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work"?

Comment: do you have up to 50 rows in that array?

Comment: @codingbiz, yes, 50 rows always returned in mysql query result, it must be said though that some of the values are null, but 50 rows in mysql output.

Comment: @BenGriffiths, thanks for your time. `<? echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[$i]['person']."</option>";` doesnt output anything, it is blank. same goes for jobs field. Thanks again,

Comment: and what is the error? have you looked at the generated html if there is any error or malformation?

Comment: Hi, generated HTML: `<td>
     <SELECT NAME=job1 id=job1 style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red"> 
     <option selected></option>     <option>
     <OPTION VALUE="clerk">clerk<OPTION VALUE="Crane Operator">Crane Operator<OPTION VALUE="data clerk">data clerk<OPTION VALUE="Executive">Executive<OPTION VALUE="manager">manager<OPTION VALUE="MHE Driver">MHE Driver<OPTION VALUE="Scaffold Rigger">Scaffold Rigger<OPTION VALUE="secretary">secretary<OPTION VALUE="test job">test job<OPTION VALUE="under water welder">under water welder 
     </option>
     </SELECT>
    </td>
`

Comment: simply a blank output, thanks @Codingbiz

Comment: if I change this to `<? echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[0]['person']."</option>"; ?>` it works, just not with $i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, worked on my machine

```
<?php
    for ( $i = 1; $i <=50; $i++ ) { 

        ?>      
            <tr>
                <td> Job <?php echo  $i; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <SELECT NAME=job<?php echo $i; ?> id=job<?php echo $i; ?> style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red"> 
                    <?php echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[$i]['job']."</option>"; ?>
                    <option>
                    <?php echo $optionjobs ?> 
                    </option>
                    </SELECT>
                </td>
                <td> Person </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $i."person: ".$dataArray[$i]['person']."job: ".$dataArray[$i]['job']; ?>

                    <SELECT NAME=person<?php echo $i; ?> id=person<?php echo $i; ?> style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red">
                    <?php echo  "<option selected>".$dataArray[$i]['person']."</option>"; ?>               
                    <option>
                    <?php echo $optionpersons ?> 
                    </option>
                    </SELECT>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks codingbiz, 100%. appreciate your time.